# Android After Adding Admob apk size increased too much

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services, filesize

Well normally (without admob) my apk size about 650 KB
after adding Admob (With Google Play Service) to apk its size become 1.5 MB

is this normal? or
are there any tool or etc. in Eclipse to know what increased the apk size?

Comment: When i used admob once, i also noticed increase in size around 600Kb. That was a long ago, though. Just look at java libs that exported in your apk and see yourself is it admob or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

650KB would be typical for Admob integration, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: thanks but I see some aplication in google play their sizes about 750 KB or less (such as Flappy Birds) and also they have advertisement.  the reason is they are using old "googleplayservice" .jar files. isn't it?

Comment: It could be they are using the old .jar files, or maybe "Flappy bird" really only takes up around 100KB of space. I can see this being possible.

Comment: Those small apk files are using standalone Admob SDK. You can decrease the size of the new one using Proguard.

Comment: Google Play Services consumes about 690 kB more than the old AdMob 6.4.1 JAR, in my own experience. This is because the old library was just a jar, but the new one contains a lot of extra images & other resources which may not be eliminated in the final APK, even if they're otherwise not used.

Comment: @LearnOpenGLES thanks for the info. I think you may be correct in that most (around 60-70%) of the excess size in OP's application is Google Play Services.